# Get div to fill up table cell

Tags: css, html-table, tablelayout

This is my use case:

```css
table {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
td { background: green; height: 300px; }
div { height: 100px; background: blue; }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>2</div>
        </td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want the divs to take up the entire part of the table cell. There shouldn't be any green in the middle cell.

Note, I don't know how big the cell is (it could be bigger than `300px`)
and I don't know how many div there will be (there can be 1 to alot)

I want to do this with css and not with javascript. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Just change the CSS for `div` like this:

```
td div {
    height: 50%;
    background: blue;
    display:block
}
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fc26yq4h/) with changed height (change height of `td` to any height you want so you see how it works)

EDIT: I didn't see you'll have different amount of divs in that td elements so the approach is different. For that purpose, first add a container div, like this:

```
table {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
td {
    background: green;
    height: 600px;
}
.box {
    display:flex;
    background: blue;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    height:100%;
    align-items: stretch;
}
.box div {
    text-align:center;
    height:auto;
    flex-grow:2
}
.red {
    background:#f00
}
.grey {
    background:#ccc
}
.yello {
    background:#fc0
}
```

Now we use a `display:flex` property with `column` orientation making sure the `.box` class (that container `div` we have added) is 100% height of that `td` so it takes the whole height.

See the [new fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/unpyfj5g/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
table {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
td { background: green; height: 300px; }
div { height: inherit; background: blue; }
```

Comment: that just makes each div 300px, In the case above I would want them to be 150 each, if there were three I would want them to be 100 each etc..